# DOMElement.scroll() doesn't scroll div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I was making a horizontally scrollable grid, I set `overflow-x: scroll;` and added two arrows. I added an event listener to both arrows to detect clicks and then scroll the grid, but the `DOMElement.scroll(options)` function is not working, the grid is not scrolled and the `scroll` event on the `DOMElement` is not fired.

```js
const vwToPx = (vw) => document.documentElement.clientWidth * vw / 100;

const scrollingArrows = document.querySelectorAll(".scroll-arrow");

scrollingArrows.forEach(arrow => {
  const parentGrid = arrow.parentElement;

  parentGrid.addEventListener("scroll", () => console.log("scroll")) // Callback not invoked which means that the scroll() method is not working

  arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const scrollLength = vwToPx(30) * 3 * (arrow.classList.contains("back-arrow") ? -1 : 1);

    console.log(parentGrid.scrollLeft, scrollLength)

    parentGrid.scroll({
      left: parentGrid.scrollLeft + scrollLength,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });

    console.log("scrolled") // Logs so the click callback is correctly set up which means that the scroll() method is not working
  })
})
```

```css
.cards-grid-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.cards-grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 30vw;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 2vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.cards-grid::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scroll-arrow {
  width: 4vw;
  height: 4vw;
  background-color: var(--light-black);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(150px / 2 + 15px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Material icons";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: black 0 0 5px;
}

.back-arrow {
  background-image: url(/images/icons/back-arrow.svg);
  left: -2vw;
  place-self: center start;
}

.forward-arrow {
  background-image: url(/images/icons/forward-arrow.svg);
  right: -2vw;
  place-self: center end;
}

.cards-grid .card {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: var(--light-black);
  padding: 2vw;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.cards-grid .card:hover {
  background-color: var(--hover-light-black);
  box-shadow: black 0px 5px 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.cards-grid .card * {
  margin: 0;
}

.cards-grid .card h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-grid-wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-arrow back-arrow"></div>
  <div class="scroll-arrow forward-arrow"></div>

  <div class="cards-grid">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach the `scroll` function to the `.cards-grid` element rather than the parent container ( it is, after all, the `.cards-grid` container that has `overflow-x: scroll;` ) and calculate the offset based upon that element it works?

The below uses a delegated listener bound to the parent `.cards-grid-wrapper` element rather than individual event listeners

```js
const vwToPx=(vw)=>document.documentElement.clientWidth * vw / 100;
const wrapper=document.querySelector('.cards-grid-wrapper');
const grid=wrapper.querySelector('.cards-grid');

wrapper.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target.classList.contains('scroll-arrow') ){
    let dir=( e.target.classList.contains('back-arrow') ) ? -1 : 1;
    let slen=vwToPx( 30 ) * 3 * dir;
    
    grid.scroll({
      left:grid.scrollLeft + slen,
      behaviou:'smooth'
    })
  }
});


grid.addEventListener('scroll',e=>{
  console.log(e.type)
});
```

```css
body{
  counter-card:reset;
}
.cards-grid-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.cards-grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 30vw;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 2vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.cards-grid::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scroll-arrow {
  width: 4vw;
  height: 4vw;
  background-color: var(--light-black);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(150px / 2 + 15px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Material icons";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: black 0 0 5px;
}

.back-arrow {
  background-image: url(/images/icons/back-arrow.svg);
  left: -2vw;
  place-self: center start;
}

.forward-arrow {
  background-image: url(/images/icons/forward-arrow.svg);
  right: -2vw;
  place-self: center end;
}

.cards-grid .card {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: var(--light-black);
  padding: 2vw;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.cards-grid .card:hover {
  background-color: var(--hover-light-black);
  box-shadow: black 0px 5px 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.cards-grid .card * {
  margin: 0;
}

.cards-grid .card h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}




.card{
  counter-increment:card;
}
.card:nth-of-type(odd){
  background:pink;
}
.card h1:after{
  content:counter(card)
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-grid-wrapper">

  <div class="scroll-arrow back-arrow"></div>
  <div class="scroll-arrow forward-arrow"></div>

  <div class="cards-grid">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh basically the issue was that i was attempting to scroll the wrapper because i moved the arrows outside of the `.cards-grid` div. Also great idea on the delegated listener.